# Efficient Way to Convert to Numeric

Tags: r

I have converted a bunch of my columns from factor to numeric, but the code was very cumbersome. I had to individually convert each column, which ended up taking more time than it should. This is the code I used (only a short sample - I actually have many more columns):

```
city1$NY <-as.numeric(levels(city1$NY))[city1$NY]   
city1$CHI<-as.numeric(levels(city1$CHI))[city1$CHI] 
city1$LA <-as.numeric(levels(city1$LA))[city1$LA]   
city1$ATL<-as.numeric(levels(city1$ATL))[city1$ATL] 
city1$MIA<-as.numeric(levels(city1$MIA))[city1$MIA]
```

I was almost positive that instead of doing all of that, I could've just done:

```
city1[,CityNames]<-as.numeric(levels(city1[,CityNames]))[city1[,CityNames]]
```

Where CityNames is just all of the columns for the data that I would like to convert.. But that doesn't work, as I get:

```
Error in as.numeric(levels(city1[, CityNames]))[city1[, CityNames]] : 
  invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong? Or is there just simply no easier way to do this task other than my long, annoying first method?

Comment: this looks like a job for the apply functions

Comment: Well that solved that.. As expected lapply worked out perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was almost positive that instead of doing all of that, I could've just done:
>
> ```
> city1[,CityNames]<-as.numeric(levels(city1[,CityNames]))[city1[,CityNames]]
> ```

So, a small change is needed:

```
city1[,CityNames] <- lapply(city1[,CityNames], function(x) as.numeric(levels(x))[x] )
```

The original approach didn't work because

- `levels` are vector-specific, so it's not clear what `myvec = levels(city1[,CityNames])` is.
- `myvec[ city1[,CityNames] ]` throws an error because `city1[,CityNames]` is a data.frame and cannot be used to subset in this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically what I do when I want to convert many columns in a data.frame to a different data type:

```
convNames <- c("NY", "CHI", "LA", "ATL", "MIA")
for(name in convNames) { city1[, name] <- as.numeric(as.character((city1[, name])) }
```

It's a nice two lines and you just have to add the names of whatever columns you want to coerce to the convNames vector to add a new column to the coercing loop below.

EDIT: Do to a factor issue, do the lapply method above.

Comment: Going straight from factor to numeric is recipe for disaster. Do `as.numeric(as.character(...))`.

Comment: Hmm, I did not know that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is faster, but may be since the lookups may be what is slowing you down. Try `city1 <- as.numeric(as.character(city1))`. The `as.character()` converts to the level values and then the `as.numeric()` interprets those strings as their a numeric equivalent. It may be significantly faster since it does not have to do any lookups into the levels vector for each value.